# Allow 2k+ users to suggest edits

Tags: feature-request, editing, suggested-edits, privileges

Every now and then, a user is unsure about an edit they make. For the under 2k rep users, this is great. It goes to the review board and is dealt with.

However, users above 2k aren't given this privilege (yes, I said privilege) of having their edits peer-reviewed.

I think that users above 2k should have the option to choose whether their edit goes to the review board or not. This can help in those occasional situations where the edit might not be right.

Maybe there can be a checkbox for "Have this edit submitted to peer review?".

This is better than doing anonymous edits as you still hold the record of the edit. It's also much easier and ties right in with SE's simplicity model.

Comment: I like this, and felt the need for it a few times. But, IMO, having the cap wouldn't be required. If a 2k+ is going to abuse it, (s)he would have abused it a long time ago. Or they would just create a new user. I don't think there is a limit on the number of suggested edits for users under 2k.

Comment: By the way, if this gets implemented or not, you can always log out or use private mode or use a different browser and edit the post as guest. This way it will go into the queue to get peer reviewd.

Comment: If you have 100K rep [for example] and suggest an edit to review still your suggest will review by 2K+ users ;)

Comment: @KasiyA: That's the idea. Rep isn't a measure of how good an editor you are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People with >2k reputation are assumed to be familiar enough with the site and its topic to be able to edit posts directly. That's why there's no peer review. If you, as an experienced user, are not sure about an edit, *then don't make the edit*!

If you feel something should be peer reviewed, then you're probably not qualified to edit it. Since you can tell that it should be reviewed, you are qualified to recognize it so just walk away. Alternatively, leave a comment explaining your edit, something like "Shouldn't foo be bar there?" or bring it up in chat and ask someone else what they think.

Answer (score 4):

They can suggest edits... just right click the edit button, "Open Link in Private Window" (FF), voila! There you go.

Comment: .... I mean as not an anonymous user.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat what would be the usage of such function? People have socks for that reason.

Comment: For 2k+ users who are not quite sure about an edit.

Comment: If you're not sure, don't edit!